# How do I extract common code from every case of an Akka 2.5 ReceiveBuilder

Tags: java, java-8, akka

I am migrating an existing codebase to Akka 2.5.1 and Java 8 (from Akka 2.4.8 / Java 7) and I have code like:

```java
public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
  /* Start type specific processing */
  if (message instanceof Foo) {
    processFoo();
  } else if (message instanceof Bar) {
    processBar();
  } else if (message instanceof Bash) {
    processBash();
  } else if (message instanceof Otherthing) {
    processOtherThing();
  }
  /* End type specific processing */

  /* Start common processing */
  doSomethingForAllMessages();
  /* End common processing */
}
```

In Akka 2.5.1 using `ReceiveBuilder` this looks like:

```java
public Receive createReceive() {
    return receiveBuilder()
        .match(Foo.class, this::processFoo)
        .match(Bar.class, this::processBar)
        .match(Bash.class, this::processBash)
        .match(OtherThing.class, this::processOtherThing)
        .build();
}
```

... except that this doesn't do the common processing `doSomethingForAllMessages()`.  Is there an idiomatic Java 8 / Akka 2.5.1 way of doing this common processing once instead of adding it to each `match()` clause?

*Update*

I am looking for something like:

```java
public Receive createReceive() {
    return receiveBuilder()
        .match(Foo.class, this::processFoo)
        .match(Bar.class, this::processBar)
        .match(Bash.class, this::processBash)
        .match(OtherThing.class, this::processOtherThing)
        .andThen(this::doSomethingForAllMessages)
        .build();
}
```

Comment: [matchAny](http://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/2.5/akka/japi/pf/ReceiveBuilder.html#matchAny-akka.japi.pf.FI.UnitApply-) meets your requirement.

Comment: I will test and see, but that doesn't match what I see in the documentation, for example at http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/java/actors.html.  I do want different behaviour on each message class, but some common processing for all messages as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you actually return is a `Receive` not a `ReceiveBuilder`. if you want to process all of the messages you can composing `scala.PartialFunction` since `Receive` is **final**. for example:

```
Receive createReceive() {
    return thenAccept(
            receiveBuilder()
                    .match(Foo.class, this::processFoo)
                    .match(Bar.class, this::processBar)
                    .match(Bash.class, this::processBash)
                    .match(OtherThing.class, this::processOtherThing)
                    .build(),
            this::doSomethingForAllMessages
    );
}

<T> Receive thenAccept(Receive origin, FI.UnitApply<T> action) {
    return new Receive(thenAccept(origin.onMessage(), action));
}

<A, B> PartialFunction<A, B> thenAccept(PartialFunction<A, B> fn,
                                    FI.UnitApply<A> action) {
    return Function.unlift(thenAccept(fn.lift(), action));
}

<A, B> Function1<A, Option<B>> thenAccept(Function1<A, Option<B>> fn,
                                      FI.UnitApply<A> action) {
    return it -> {
        Option<B> value = fn.apply(it);
        action.apply(it);
        return value;
    };
}
```

**IF** you don't want to operate `scala` api to achieve your needs. for some reason, e.g: `Function1` is not a @FunctionalInterface in `scala` in prior version. you can composing `ReceiveBuilder`s. for example:

```
public Receive createReceive() {
    return thenAccept(
            receiveBuilder()
                    .match(Foo.class, this::processFoo)
                    .match(Bar.class, this::processBar)
                    .match(Bash.class, this::processBash)
                    .match(OtherThing.class, this::processOtherThing),
            this::doSomethingForAllMessages
    ).build();
}

ReceiveBuilder thenAccept(ReceiveBuilder origin, FI.UnitApply<Object> action) {
    return ReceiveBuilder.create().matchAny(allOf(
            origin.build().onMessage()::apply,
            action
    ));
}

FI.UnitApply<Object> allOf(FI.UnitApply<Object>... actions) {
    return it -> {
        for (FI.UnitApply<Object> action : actions) {
            action.apply(it);
        }
    };
}
```

**OR** you can keeping semantics consistency by combine `ReceiveBuilder`s.

```
public Receive createReceive() {
    return both(
            receiveBuilder()
                    .match(Foo.class, this::processFoo)
                    .match(Bar.class, this::processBar)
                    .match(Bash.class, this::processBash)
                    .match(OtherThing.class, this::processOtherThing),
            receiveBuilder().matchAny(this::doSomethingForAllMessages)
    ).build();
}

ReceiveBuilder both(ReceiveBuilder left, ReceiveBuilder right) {
    return ReceiveBuilder.create().matchAny(it -> Stream.of(left,right)
            .map(ReceiveBuilder::build)
            .map(Receive::onMessage)
            .forEach(action->action.apply(it)));
}
```

**OR** the `thenAccept` behavior looks like belongs to `ReceiveBuilder`, but you need take more efforts to achieve it, and it break **encapsulation** when using *inheritance*.

```
public Receive createReceive() {
    return AcceptableReceiveBuilder.create()
                  .match(Foo.class, this::processFoo)
                  .match(Bar.class, this::processBar)
                  .match(Bash.class, this::processBash)
                  .match(OtherThing.class, this::processOtherThing)
                  .thenAccept(this::doSomethingForAllMessages)
                  .build();
}



class AcceptableReceiveBuilder extends ReceiveBuilder {
    private List<FI.UnitApply<Object>> afterActions = new ArrayList<>();

    public static AcceptableReceiveBuilder create() {
        return new AcceptableReceiveBuilder();
    }

    @Override
    public
    <P> AcceptableReceiveBuilder match(Class<P> type, FI.UnitApply<P> action) {
        return this.matchUnchecked(type, action);
    }

    @Override
    public
    AcceptableReceiveBuilder matchUnchecked(Class<?> type,
                                            FI.UnitApply<?> action) {
        return (AcceptableReceiveBuilder) super.matchUnchecked(type
                , compose(action));
    }

    @Override
    public
    <P> AcceptableReceiveBuilder match(Class<P> type,
                                       FI.TypedPredicate<P> condition,
                                       FI.UnitApply<P> action) {
        return this.matchUnchecked(type, condition, action);
    }

    @Override
    public
    <P> AcceptableReceiveBuilder matchUnchecked(Class<?> type,
                                                FI.TypedPredicate<?> condition,
                                                FI.UnitApply<P> action) {
        return (AcceptableReceiveBuilder) super.matchUnchecked(type, condition
                , compose(action));
    }

    @Override
    public
    <P> AcceptableReceiveBuilder matchEquals(P value, FI.UnitApply<P> action) {
        return (AcceptableReceiveBuilder) super.matchEquals(value
                , compose(action));
    }

    @Override
    public
    <P> AcceptableReceiveBuilder matchEquals(P value,
                                             FI.TypedPredicate<P> condition,
                                             FI.UnitApply<P> action) {
        return (AcceptableReceiveBuilder) super.matchEquals(value, condition
                , compose(action));
    }

    @Override
    public
    AcceptableReceiveBuilder matchAny(FI.UnitApply<Object> action) {
        return (AcceptableReceiveBuilder) super.matchAny(compose(action));
    }

    private
    <P> FI.UnitApply<P> compose(FI.UnitApply<P> action) {
        return value -> {
            action.apply(value);
            for (FI.UnitApply<Object> it : afterActions) {
                it.apply(value);
            }
        };
    }

    public
    AcceptableReceiveBuilder thenAccept(FI.UnitApply<Object> action) {
        afterActions.add(action);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks like what I want, I will test it out tomorrow and let you know

Comment: @holi-java when we have two instances (one for backup) with the actor system, everything happens twice. Is there any way to solve this issue?