# How do I advance to the next state, without repeating the same condition evaluation for each received message?

Tags: c#, akka.net

I have an actor that needs to collect data from various sources, before it can continue processing. Currently, I repeat the same condition evaluation for each received message:

```
private Foo foo;
private Bar bar;

private void DoSomething(DoSomething message)
{
    this.BecomeWaitingForInputData();

    this.GetFoo(message.FooId); /* sends message */
    this.GetBar(message.BarId); /* sends message */
}

private void BecomeWaitingForInputData()
{
    this.Become(() =>
    {
        this.Receive<Foo>((message) =>
        {
            this.CollectFoo(message); /* assigns to foo */
            this.ProcessInputDataIfReady();
        });

        this.Receive<Bar>((message) =>
        {
            this.CollectBar(message); /* assigns to bar */
            this.ProcessInputDataIfReady();
        });
    });
}

private void ProcessInputDataIfReady()
{
    if (this.foo == null || this.bar == null) return;
    /* ... */
    this.BecomeWaitingForProcessResults();
}
```

Is there a way to avoid repeating `this.ProcessInputDataIfReady();`, or is this the best possible way to write it? Most examples (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44054913/247702)) I could find are written in Scala, which seems to allow all kinds of fancy stuff with its syntax, and for which I don't really see an equivalent in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`FSM<>` class in Akka.NET -docs-](http://getakka.net/api/Akka.Actor.FSM-2.html) [-source-](https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/blob/dev/src/core/Akka/Actor/FSM.cs), which allows you to return the next behavior upon processing each event.

The `ReceiveActor` as it's currently written doesn't allow for the nice `AndThen` type of operators that Scala has, so if you want to stick with this design you're probably doing it the least painful way now as far as I can tell.

Comment: I had a brief look at the docs of the `FSM` class, and it seems to be exactly what I need. When you say "The `ReceiveActor` as it's currently written", does that mean some changes are in the pipeline?

Comment: I've been rewriting my actor as an `FSM` today, and once you get the hang of it, it's a pleasure to work with. I especially like the `FsmEvent.Match().With<>()` syntax that I found in the source code, it doesn't seem to be documented anywhere currently?

Comment: @Stijn no, we don't have any docs for it at the moment. It's something we should definitely add.